How to set a session time interval from the day before until the next day?
I've coded a simple cumulative volume indicator which cumulates the volume inside a user-specified time interval. How can I edit the code, so that the indicator will work when I set the start time at a time the day before and the end time will be a time the next day (e.g. extended trading hours from 4 pm the previous day to 9:30 am the next day)?
//@version=5
indicator("Custom Session Cumulative Volume", overlay = false)

session_time = input.session("0400-0930", title = "Session Time")

var int start_hour = na
var int start_minute = na
var int end_hour = na
var int end_minute = na

if (bar_index == 0) 
    start_hour := int(str.tonumber(str.substring(session_time, 0, 2)))
    start_minute := int(str.tonumber(str.substring(session_time, 2, 4)))
    end_hour := int(str.tonumber(str.substring(session_time, 5, 7)))
    end_minute := int(str.tonumber(str.substring(session_time, 7, 9)))

session_start_time = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, start_hour, start_minute)
session_end_time = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, end_hour, end_minute)

in_session = (time >= session_start_time and time < session_end_time)

var float cum_vol = 0.0
if (in_session)
    cum_vol := cum_vol + volume
else
    cum_vol := 0

plot(cum_vol, style = plot.style_histogram, color = color.blue, linewidth = 2)

